# The difference between return statements in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, struts

What is the difference between returning a `SUCCESS` and `Action.SUCCESS` for your execute method in struts 2? I know about returning a `SUCCESS` string, but I couldn't figure the `Action.SUCCESS` one?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.1/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Action.java#Action) code of `Action`:

`public static final String SUCCESS = "success";`

I think that this line explains better than any words that `Action.SUCCESS` and string constant `"success"` are the same.

Comment: So why not use Just "success" rather than defining a constant variable?

Comment: @link because it is a better practice to use constant fields instead of typing the constant value every time. And if the value changes you have exactly one place where you have to change it. Furthermore the IDE will let you know if you accidently type `Success` which would not be the case if you typed "Success" and such errors tend to be hard to find

Answer (score 2):

`Action.SUCCESS` is a `String` constant defined in the `Action` interface. [see here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Action.html#SUCCESS)

It will be available in all your Action classes that implement this interface. Your own action classes inherit this constant.

So there is practically no difference between `Action.SUCCESS` and `SUCCESS` inside a class that implements `Action`.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same if point to the same constant in `Action` class. But to use the first case required either the action class to implement the `Action` interface better with extending the `ActionSupport` which implements the `Action` interface or use static imports. The second case is the usual way to access static resources.

Answer (score 1):

They are both string mapped to "success" string.

```
public interface Action {

    /**
     * The action execution was successful. Show result
     * view to the end user.
     */
    public static final String SUCCESS = "success";
```

Comment: Iif the action class implements `Action`.